# Should I try to minimize potential for discovery of usernames via account creation?

Tags: security, authentication

So I have accounts with logins in my system.

If someone wants to create a new account, obviously they can't use the same login.

As a result, the account creation form/system itself allows one to discover usernames already in the system (for example, if you try to create an account with the username "Admin", it would either allow or reject you, allowing you to know whether there is a username "Admin" to try a password against or not.  Similiarly, if you try to create an account "john", it'll tell you whether a john account exists and you can start testing john's password).

Is there a way to minimize this effect?  Or should I just not worry about this discovery tactic, and effectively assume that usernames are public info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard is to assume that usernames are public.

If they aren't, the only things I could suggest:

- Assign usernames (ex, “your username is `5829103`”)
- Force all names to have a server-assigned suffix (ex, `wolever1242`)
- Randomly deny usernames (ie, to make that kind of discovery harder)

But… All of those kind of suck.

A better question would be: what attack vectors are opened when an attacker gets access to a username? In general, there aren't many, and they can be mitigated through other policies (ex, limiting the number of login attempts per username per minute, or making sure that phone reps authenticate the caller using some secret in addition to username).

Comment: Well, the attack vectors that are opened up are just about the most important ones there are, I'd say, since you can go from knowing 0% of a login to 20-50% of it.  I guess the problem is: If accounts are of strong importance, usernames should be in no way shape or form discoverable, and thus what can be used as a username should be limited (e.g. require a number or a minimum length limit) I suppose.  So that important accounts get strong usernames.

Comment: A minimum length for usernames does suck less than the things I suggested, but it still isn't great (ex, I know an `ajr` would wouldn't be too happy if he had to pick another name). If you're really concerned with usability, I would instead stick a rate limiter on the “check username” call. If I can only check 10 usernames a minute, it's going to take a long time to enumerate all the four letter usernames.

Comment: (actually, I've also had at least one bug report filed against me by a fellow with a two character username… Since then, I've only required one character names :P)

Comment: Right, but I guess the best rate limiting at that point is going to be one by ip, which just means they'll need to sue a proxy.  I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: That's true… And rate limiting is only one method. If security is important you could use some kind of two-factor auth, the bank-style masked passwords, etc. If it were me, I wouldn't think about making usernames difficult to guess until I'd implemented all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much that can be done about that. You need to show them something to verify whether the username is available, so it's kind of unavoidable.

Even if it does nothing, by the fact that the account was not created with that username, they would still be able to surmise that the username is unavailable, albeit with less convenience.

Comment: Well, the ironic thing is that I can make login more secure than I can account creation in this regard, because I can make sure there's a username and password match before confirming that there's an account to match against.  In other words, even if there's an admin account, logging in with admin + wrongpassword will yeild the same message whether there's an admin account or not, which makes it annoying that account creation allows such a discovery.

Comment: @Tchalvak: You're absolutely right, which is why I found this question so interesting. That vulnerability had never really occurred to me before. Really good question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
As often, it is about Security Vs. Useability.
Having a captcha will prevent *automated* account discovery.